# 'dependent name is not a type' when using nested nested class in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Does anyone know why the following fails to compile (tested in MSVC2015)?

```
template<int N> // when this line is removed it compiles successfully
class A {
    class B {
    public:
        class C {
        };
    };
    void func(B b){} // compiles fine
    void func(B::C c){} // generates warning C4346 and error C2061
};
```

It generates the following on the line marked with a comment:

- `warning C4346: 'A<N>::B::C': dependent name is not a type`
- `error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'C'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's google it for you.

> The `typename` keyword is required if a dependent name is to be treated as a type.

C++ rule.

> **14.6 Name resolution**
>
> A name used in a template declaration or deﬁnition and that is *dependent* on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup ﬁnds a type name or the name is qualiﬁed by the keyword `typename`.

Comment: What is a 'dependent name'?

Comment: Edited. See above.

Comment: Is there a reason for the rule?

Comment: @Museful yes. This is because accessing a data member or a member type, and even a member template is an ambiguous syntax. Imagine `foo::bar` is that a type? is that a static data member? The compiler assumes a data member unless the `typename` keyword is there.