# Dependent name in local class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Ts>
void boo()
{
    struct A
    {
        struct B {};
    };
    static_assert(std::is_class_v<A>);
    static_assert(std::is_class_v<A::B>); // compilation failure; need typename.
}

int main()
{
    boo<int>();
}
```

Why is `A::B` a dependent name and `A` is not?
Can not see anything in standard about that.

Comment: Basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226871, but it was closed with the wrong target. The template-typename canonical doesn't cover this afaict.

Comment: @cigien That Q is different. Nested class (outside of function) can be specialized, that's why it's dependent. In this case you can't reference the classes to specialize them (I think?), so this looks like a defect to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, good point, here the nested class is inside a function, so it's not even a duplicate.

Comment: I think is about lexical. Complier think `B` of `A::B` is static member. But we can fix by add explicit  mark `std::is_class_v<typename A::B>` .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [CWG 2074](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2074), which is still unresolved [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### 2074. Type-dependence of local class of function template
>
> According to 13.8.3.2 [temp.dep.type] paragraph 9, a local class in a
> function template is dependent if and only if it contains a subobject
> of a dependent type. However, given an example like
>
> ```
>   template<typename T> void f() {
>     struct X {
>       typedef int type;
>   #ifdef DEPENDENT
>       T x;
>   #endif
>     };
>   X::type y;    // #1
>   }
>   void g() { f<int>(); }
> ```
>
> there is **implementation variance** in the treatment of #1, but **whether
> or not DEPENDENT is defined appears to make no difference.**
>
> [...]
>
> Perhaps the right answer is that the types should be dependent but a member of the current instantiation, permitting name lookup without typename.
>
> **Additional notes (September, 2022):**
>
> At present, **the term "current instantiation" is defined for class
> templates only, and thus does not apply to function templates**.
>
> Moreover, the resolution for this issue should also handle local
> enums, with particular attention to 9.7.2 [enum.udecl] paragraph 1:
>
> The elaborated-enum-specifier shall not name a dependent type and...
> This rule, without amendment, would disallow the following reasonable
> example if local enums were made dependent types:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> void f() {
>   enum class E { e1, e2 };
>   using enum E;
> }
> ```

The spec appears underspecified, as vendors seems to (on an implementation variance basis) enforce [[temp.dep.type]/7.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type#7.3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> /7 A type is dependent if it is
>
> - [...]
> - /7.3 **a nested class** or enumeration that is a direct member of **a class that is the current instantiation**,

But as noted in CWG 2074, *current instantiation* as per [[temp.dep.type]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type#1) does not cover what are actually the rules for the case of function templates.